# Email - Field "From": Possible security issues

Tags: email, security, smtp, html-email

I have a question concerning the security of the `from` field that we find in emails.

Here's the use case: I want to allow some customers to send emails to their third parties through a Java application.
The `from` address is always the same and it is an email managed by the application. But I want to allow my customers to set a custom name in the `from` field. For example:

```
From: John Doe <noreply@myapp.com>
```

So in this example, `noreply@myapp.com` is one of the application email but `John Doe` is a value submitted by the customer.

I'd like to know what are the possible security issues?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to validate, sanitize and escape user input.

If your app allow the customers to control the body and the recipient be aware they can send mails that looks like your own mail. The recipient not always check the address, he look at the name and the name can say 'ymansour'